# Testing if a site is vulnerable to Sql Injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I was reading about sql injection and i understand how it works if there is a form where the user can enter his username and login. What i dont get is how websites without a login page can be vulnerable to sql injection.

http://thecybersaviours.com/how-to-find-out-if-a-website-is-vulnerable-to-sql-injection

It says just append a ' or ''=' to test it. I dont understand how this helps to determine whether an error exists. Where is the query being constructed at all.

Comment: ANY textbox or input on any page where the user can type and enter data can have SQL injection if the user's entry is passed into a SQL command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SQL injection is the attempt to issue SQL commands to a database through a website interface, to gain other information. Namely, this information is stored database information such as usernames and passwords.

First rule of securing any script or page that attaches to a database instance is **Do not trust user input**.

Your example is attempting to end a misquoted string in an SQL statement. To understand this, you first need to [understand SQL statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL). In your example of adding a `'` to a paramater, your 'injection' is hoping for the following type of statement:

> SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='$username'

By appending a `'` to that statement, you could then add additional SQL paramaters or queries.: `' OR username --`

> SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='' OR username -- '$username

*That* is an injection (one type of; Query Reshaping). The user input becomes an *injected* statement into the pre-written SQL statement.

Generally there are three types of SQL injection methods:

- Query Reshaping or redirection (above)
- Error message based (No such user/password)
- Blind Injections

Read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [How to test for vulnerabilities](http://www.testingsecurity.com/how-to-test/injection-vulnerabilities/SQL-Injection), [understanding and overcoming SQL injection](http://www.lassosoft.com/Understanding-and-Overcoming-SQL-Injection), and this question (and related ones) on StackOverflow [about avoiding injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks).

Edit:

As far as TESTING your site for SQL injection, understand it gets A LOT more complex than just 'append a symbol'. If your site is critical, and you (or your company) can afford it, hire a professional pen tester. Failing that, [this great exaxmple/proof](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) can show you some common techniques one might use to perform an injection test. There is also [SQLMap](http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/) which can automate some tests for SQL Injection and database take over scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

SQL Injection can be done on any input the user can influence that isn't properly escaped before used in a query.

One example would be a get variable like this:

```
http//www.example.com/user.php?userid=5
```

Now, if the accompanying PHP code goes something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE userid=" . $_GET['userid'];
// ...
```

You can easily use SQL injection here too:

```
http//www.example.com/user.php?userid=5 AND 1=2 UNION SELECT password,username FROM users WHERE usertype='admin'
```

(of course, the spaces will have to be replaced by `%20`, but this is more readable. Additionally, this is just an example making some more assumptions, but the idea should be clear.)

Answer (score 2):

Any input from a client are ways to be vulnerable. Including all forms and the query string. This includes all HTTP verbs.

There are 3rd party solutions that can crawl an application and detect when an injection could happen.

Answer (score 1):

A login page isn't the only part of a database-driven website that interacts with the database.

Any user-editable input which is used to construct a database query is a potential entry point for a SQL injection attack.  The attacker may not necessarily login to the site as an admin through this attack, but can do other things.  They can change data, change server settings, etc. depending on the nature of the application's interaction with the database.

Appending a `'` to an input is usually a pretty good test to see if it generates an error or otherwise produces unexpected behavior on the site.  It's an indication that the user input is being used to build a raw query and the developer didn't expect a single quote, which changes the query structure.

Keep in mind that one page may be secure against SQL injection while another one may not.  The login page, for example, may be hardened against such attacks.  But a different page elsewhere in the site might be wide open.  So, for example, if one wanted to login as an admin then one can use the SQL injection on that other page to change the admin password.  Then return to the perfectly non-SQL-injectable login page and login as the admin.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to protect yourself is to use stored procedures instead of inline SQL statements.

Then use "least privilege" permissions and only allow access to stored procedures and not directly to tables.

Comment: **Caution:** The act of using stored procedures is not *by itself* a protection against SQL injection.  One still needs to understand what one is doing.  http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2012/01/stored-procedures-and-sql-injection.html

Comment: You are correct. Using stored procedures can protect you from SQL injection when the person writing them, knows how to use them. 

But we could say the same for just about everything else. SQL server security works, when the DBA knows what he is doing.

Or how about a developer showing the connection string in an error message, so the list goes on and one.

I guess what I am trying to say, is that minimal grade of experience or talent is expected.

Comment: Indeed.  I just want to avoid misinterpretation from beginner users (such as the OP) who may tend to run away with the wrong implications of a statement.  Make the world a better place and all that :)

Answer (score 0):

The test has to be done on a page that queries a database so yes typically that is a login page because it's the page that can do the most harm but could be an unsecure page as well.

Generally you would have your database queries behind a secure login but if you just have a listing of items or something that you don't care if the world sees a hacker could append some sql injection to the end of the querystring.

The key with SQL Injection is the person doing the injection would have to know that your querying a database so if your not querying a database then no sql inject can be done. If your form is submitting to a database then yes they could SQL Inject that.  It's always good practice to use either stored procedures to select/insert/update/delete or make sure you prepare or escape out all the statements that will be hitting the database.